# WPF access name of Usercontrol button from parent

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to trigger a storyboard animation when the click event of a button in a usercontrol 
is clicked. The parent doesn't recognise the name of the button within the usercontrol
ie trying  UserControl.MyButton as SourceName doesn't work. How can I access the name of the button and use in the SourceName for the EventTrigger
Here is the pseudo code of main window

```
      <Window>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="???" >
                <BeginStoryboard >
                   -----------------------
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

             <UserControl  />
       </Window>
```

Here is the user control defined in separate xaml

```
           <UserControl>
             <Button  x:Name="MyButton" /> 
       </UserControl>
```

Comment: That won't work. Your UserControl should expose its own Click event.

Comment: There must be a way of accessing the x:Name value of the Button surely

Comment: If I had the usercontrol xaml in the same file it is easy, I just shifted the code to another xaml so the main window xaml file isn't too big

Comment: No, the UserControl's XAML and that of the MainWindow are different name scopes.

Comment: OK had to raise custom click event, seems a lot for just refactoring but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems that SourceName does not have to be an element in the current namescope. The following code works for Button1 and not for Button2. EvenTrigger should be checking the original source name when handling the event:

```
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="Button1">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation To="30" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="Text" FontSize="12" />
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="UC"  />
</StackPanel>

 <UserControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button  x:Name="Button1" Content="Click"/>
        <Button  x:Name="Button2" Content="Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Edited my post, as it previously contained some incorrect info.